# Why the output is printed in int instead of float?

Tags: c++, floating-point

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 float a,b;
 cin>>a>>b;
 cout<<a*b*1.05;

 return 0;
}
```

When I take the input as 232 and 1234 the output should be 300602.4, but the output is printed as 300602. Even when I take the input as 232.0 and 1234.0 still I get same result. I know that to print the output in float I have to use this  `cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << a * b * 1.05 << endl;`. But, I want to know why am I not getting output in float, even if operands are float.

Input:

```
232.0
1234.0
```

Output:

```
300602
```

Comment: It outputs up to 6 significant digits.

Comment: If you want to get the maximum precision for `float` you can set it with `std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10 + 1);` - It's usually 7 so you'll get the result `300602.4`. Perhaps use `double`s instead where the max precision is 16.

Comment: @RaKo " even if operands are float" --> `"cout<<a*b*1.05;"` looks like code is trying to print a `double`, not a `float` as the multiplication is `float*float*double` with a `double` product.

Comment: Minor point: `int` and `float` are data types. Objects of those types hold values that can be displayed as text. The tect is not `int` or `float`; it's just text. The issue in the question is about the **conversion** of values to text.